# Can't upload image to MySQL by using nodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, image, multer

I want to upload a image to database MySQL, MySQL data type I setting is longblob.

Multer is using with a middleware.

the problem is when I print the image array on console is OK,

but upload to database I will got an error and image array will become random code.

`upload error on cmd` => [upload error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FfrT.png)

below is nodeJS code

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({ host: 'localhost', user: 'adam', password: 'good1234', database: 'car2' });

// Set The Storage Engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage(
  {
  destination: './public/uploads/',
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null,file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));},
  }
);

// Init Upload
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  }
}).single('myImage');

// Check File Type
function checkFileType(file, cb){
  // Allowed ext
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
  // Check ext
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  // Check mime
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if(mimetype && extname){
    return cb(null,true);
  } else {
    cb('Error: Images Only!');
  }
}

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if(err){
      res.render('index', {
        msg: err
      });
    } else {
      if(req.file == undefined){
        res.render('index', {
          msg: 'Error: No File Selected!'
        });
      } else {
        console.log(req.file);
        console.log("req.file.path",req.file.path);

        var img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);

        con.connect(function (error) {
          if (error) throw error;

          console.log("connect OK!");
          var current_date = new Date(Date.now() + 8 * 3600 * 1000);
          var sql = `INSERT INTO image (image_data, upload_time,) VALUES (${img},${current_date.toISOString()});`;
          con.query(sql, function (error, result) {
            if (error) throw error;

            console.log('upload complete');
          });
        });

        res.render('index', {
          msg: 'File Uploaded!',
          file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}`
        });
      }
    }
  });
});

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: That's SQL injection at its best. You can't just add random binary streams in the middle of a SQL command.  Please check your database library documentation for an example on how to bind parameters.

Comment: This is the first library that shows up in Google, it's probably the one you're using: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#user-content-performing-queries